# New JSLint: "Unexpected '.'." explanation

Tags: javascript, jslint

Using the new JSLint, I get the following error for the following code:

> Unexpected '.'.

```
return (elem || document).querySelector(selector);
```

This seems really odd, as I can't imagine why the `(something || something-else).method-call` notation would be less than ideal.

Does anyone know why the new JSLint throws this error (when the old one never did)?
Thanks.

Comment: JSLint is less than ideal.

Comment: New and old doesn't make much sense. Can you include the actual versions?

Comment: Sorry. "New" is "JSLint edition 2015-07-01", and old is basically before JSLint Beta, which was rolled out a few months ago at most.

Comment: squint, what's more ideal?

Comment: http://jshint.com Doesn't come with the baggage of Crockford's opinions.

Comment: JSHint doesn't throw an error; that is nice. Thanks.

Comment: That code works fine in jsHint.com.

Comment: It may be that jsLint wants you to do this: `return ((elem || document).querySelector(selector));` though that is not required by the language as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/n73sLq86/

Comment: @jfriend00: Nope. It wants you to use a variable for the bit in parens. `var foo = elem || document; return foo.querySelector(selector);` This is yet another case of what squint was alluding to: Crockford's opinions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - further reason why I never use JSLint then.  Too much of someone else's opinion about how code should be written.

Comment: @jfriend00: **Big.** **Time.** :-)

Comment: Worth mentioning that since it does work in old.jslint.com, it might be an unintentional oversight for the new version. Consider asking [on the JSLint Google+ community](https://plus.google.com/communities/104441363299760713736). Harry Whitfield has a streak of finding unintentional bugs in the new code that've been quickly fixed. And [if you don't like JSLint, don't use it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKIcaejkpD4&t=1m16s). But it makes getting a large team on the same page so much faster, and with so many fewer subjective timesink arguments. I've never seen Crockford be *wrong*, Walter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be a bug in the new version. It works if you change it to this:

```
var source = elem || document;
return source.querySelector(selector);
```

So either it's a bug, or Crockford wants you to factor the `||` expression out of that. (There's an argument for it: For instance, it makes it easier to see what's going to get used if you were stepping through it in the debugger. But the sheer volume of code that would start failing if this were a new rule is **huge**...)

---

There are plenty of alternatives to JSLint, including [JSHint](http://jshint.com/). It was originally (a *long* time ago) a fork of JSLint, but it's since seen a huge amount of development and gone its own way.

Comment: T.J., thank you so much for this. This is exactly what I was looking for: both a reason for the error and an easy solution. With that said, I also like everyone's response of simply "don't use JSLint; use JSHint". There was a time (with older, and I think more lenient versions of JSLint) in which I followed JSLint to the T and make sure there were no errors. However, I don't feel that way anymore, especially with the newer versions of JSLint. Things like no for (in) loops allowed, the issue above, it throwing an error if you use `arguments`, etc. just make it too extreme. I've also...

Comment: Learned to just go more down the path of, "JSLint is a great tool, but I don't always have to agree with Crockford 100%." As long as I understand why any errors it's throwing are being thrown and I can live with that, I think that that is more than acceptable.